# Transform date values into year variable

Tags: r, date, variables, posixct

I have a column of dates (yyyy/mm/dd), and want to create the variable "year", with only values of the years from each observation

I tried with this code, but that doesn't work, because it assigns numeric values starting from the origin.

```
df$year<-as.POSIXct(df$date,format="%Y",origin="1970-01-01")

df$year<- as.numeric(df$year)
```

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: `df$year <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(df$date), "%Y"))`

Comment: Or ’df$year <- lubridate::year(df$date)’